# Чтение из файла и обработка данных

Tags: python, python-3.x

есть такой вопрос:

Есть какие-то данные в файле, хочу чтобы в функции я эту информацию извлёк и переобразить это значение в переменной чтобы дальше другая функция использовала эту переменную.

начеркал какие то способы которые в голове пришли но не получается :(

```
f = open('txt.txt', 'r')
y = f.read()
for x in y:
    new_list = {x}
```

данные в файле:

```
exp=2020 ( функция должна записывать все линии в словаре,  а потом с словаря я бы легко перенёс нужное значение,то есть с EXP значение 2020, в переменную)
anjelo=2021
```

в итоге получаю в new_list - {'1'} , но не понимаю откуда эта 1 берётся.

Comment: `for x in y` — вы циклом перебираете каждый символ в строке. `new_list = {x}` — для каждого символа вы создаёте новое множество. Соответственно, когда цикл дойдёт до последнего символа `'1'` (ведь в конце файла у вас написано 2021, значит последний символ это 1), будет создано множество `new_list = {'1'}`

Comment: Понял вас, я только что сообразил это.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы читаете строки, а не словарь. Необходимо обрабатывать строки одну за одной

```py
result = {}
with open('txt.txt', 'r') as f:
   lines = f.readlines()
   for line in lines:
       key, value = line.split("=")
       result[key] = value
```

Читаем с помощью `readlines()` метода, который возвращает все строки в файле. Дальше пробегаемся по всем строкам по отдельности. Каждую строку разделить по символу `=` и распаковать в две переменные `key` и `value`. Дальше сохранить в словарь `result` данные из строки

Вывод

```
>>> print(result)
{'exp':'2020', 'anjelo':'2021'}
```

Comment: Ой спасибо. вроде всё просто и понятно, но сам никак не могу дойти до этого... Наверное со временем это придёт... Спасибо еще раз Дмитрий!

Comment: `lines = f.readlines()
   for line in lines:` вроде можно заменить на `for line in f:`?

Comment: @TemoKvartskhava на здоровье, не забывайте [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Qwertiy тут по слогам, чтобы ТС не путался